# How do OEMs install thousands of windows'ses on the machines they sell?

Tags: windows, installation, oem

Imagine I was an OEM and I was selling thousands of PCs every day, everyone of them comes preinstalled with windows.

I see how custom Windows-CDs will help me (installing drivers, software, using a specific multi-use product key and so on), but how does that Windows still get on the HD?

Are there machines opening the CD-drives, putting a CD in there, closing it and rebooting the system so that the installation can proceed automatically? Are there people who do that? Can hard-drives be manufactured the way that some data is already on there? (I imagine this to be very hard, but not impossible in principle)?

This question is a bit of and weird maybe, but I cannot imagine people manually installing Windows on every of those machines.

Does anyone know how the big OEMs do that?

Answer (score 2):

They install Windows once onto a hard drive, which becomes a master for a particular hardware configuration.

There is a utility called sysprep that is run on that system which puts the system into a sort of "almost-finished-installation" state. The system is then shut down.

This drive is then cloned to the drives that get installed in the systems to be shipped.

The cloning is done on a machine with a whole lot of SATA ports and removable drive trays. It takes a LOT less time than installing Windows, especially since they do a lot of them at once.

When the new system is booted, it boots into this "almost-finished-installation" state where it goes through hardware detection  generates a unique system security ID, asks you for a name and password for your account, etc., just as if you had started with a fresh disk and installed Windows yourself.

The mechanism allows for a unique Windows product key to be written to a special file on the disk. This is done individually to each drive after it's been cloned. OEM-specific post-installation procedures are also allowed for.